# Genius/KYE tablet driver issues

Tags: drivers, kernel, tablet, xinput, graphics-tablet

So I installed an alternative driver for my Genius EasyPen i405X, because of a game called McOsu. It’s mainly played with a graphics tablet, so I wanted the proper drivers (which are essential to have good gameplay), installing the driver was fine, it was an extension to xinput, but setting the values of the driver wasn’t. The following errors occurred.

(If there’s another way to change the area of a non-Wacom tablet, I would be happy to hear it.)

```
xinput set-prop "Genius EasyPen i405X" --type=float "Coordinate Transformation Matrix" 2 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0.5
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
  Serial number of failed request:  19
  Current serial number in output stream:  20
```

Output of `xinput list-props "Genius EasyPen i405X"`:

```
Device 'Genius EasyPen i405X':
    Device Enabled (150):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (152): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Node (274):  "/dev/input/event19"
    Device Product ID (275):    1112, 20496
```

Comment: What is output of `xinput list-props "Genius EasyPen i405X"`?   Put in [pastebin](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/), and link in question.

Comment: I did it, can you help me?

Comment: Output of `xinput list-props` wasn't as helpful as I'd hoped... I tried the command you used with the touchscreen on my computer without problem (other than that it maps the corner of the touchpad to the entire screen). Looks you're unlikely to find a solution here because the problem is probably caused by the alternative driver you're using. Try switching back to a standard driver or contacting the alternative-driver developers.